# How to change text color as per background color using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change text color as per background between lighter to darker color.

What I wanted to do as below:

`[background Color]       + -------- -       Text with Background`

So here if I choose background **Green** then "**Text with background**" text color can switch from lighter color to darker color using **+ -**

I've used below code.

**Code**

```
<input type="range" name="bgopacity" id="bgopacity" value="0" min="0" max="765" step="1" onchange="rangevalue.value=value">

<span class="txtcolor">Text With Background</span>

<script>
    var rval = bval = gval = 0;
    $('#bgopacity').on('change keyup mouseout keypress click mouseenter mouseup', function (value) {

        var valcnt = $(this).val();

        if (valcnt <= 255) {
            rval = valcnt;
            gval = bval = 0;
        } else if (valcnt >= 255 && valcnt <= 510) {
            rval = 255;
            gval = valcnt - rval;
            bval = 0;
        } else if (valcnt >= 510) {
            rval =  gval = 255;
            bval = valcnt - (gval + rval);
        }

        $('.txtcolor').css('color','rgb('+Math.round(rval)+','+Math.round(gval)+','+Math.round(bval)+')');
    });
</script>
```

This code is working perfectly, but only some colors are changing. So I need more color switch between 0 to 765.

Can you please help me to find out relative code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want to have the user pick a color and, after that, have a slider that allows the user to lighten or darken the color selected.

Instead of the **RGB model** (0 - 255 for Red, Green and Blue, respectively), I'd recommend you check out the [**HSL model**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV).

HSL stands for *Hue* , *Saturation* and *Luminosity*. This [CodePen project](http://codepen.io/nw/pen/wsnhu) demonstrates very well how HSL and RGB differ.

- The **Hue** is an angle from 0° - 360° (the `deg` suffix in CSS is optional)

  - It defines *what color* you're working with. Red is at 0°, green is at 120° and blue is at 240°, looping back to red at 360°. You can pick any of the beautiful nuances of color in between 0° and 360°.

    [image: hue screenshot]
- The **Saturation** is a percentage from 0% to 100% (with the `%` suffix in CSS)

  - It defines *how colorful* the color is. 100% saturation means the color is at its full potential. 0% saturation is just a sad, gray mess.

    [image: saturation screenshot]
- The **Luminosity** is a percentage from 0% to 100% (with the `%` suffix in CSS)

  - It defines *how bright* the color is, how close it is to being black or white.

    [image: luminosity screenshot]

The `hsl()` usage in CSS is very similar to the `rgb()`'s:

```css
element {
    color: hsl(190, 90%, 55%);  /* this is a beautiful cyan color */
}
```

Basically, where in RGB you have to pick the amount of each color to add up, in HSL you can pick *what color* and *what to do with it*.

---

So, in your case, the user would first choose the H (`hue`) part, which defines what *color* it is.

Then you could have a slider for L (`luminosity`), and let the user define just how bright the background color is.

---

Here's a working example of your task, but with HSL (I've added saturation as well but it can be easily removed if unnecessary):

```js
var hue_picker = document.getElementById("hue-picker");
var sat_picker = document.getElementById("sat-picker");
var lum_picker = document.getElementById("lum-picker");
var txt = document.getElementById("txt");
var div = document.getElementById("div");

function filter_input(input, min, max) {
    return Math.max(min, Math.min(input, max))
}

function update_color() {
    // Filter out inputs that are greater than max or lesser than min
    var hue = filter_input(hue_picker.value, 0, 360);
    var sat = filter_input(sat_picker.value, 0, 100);
    var lum = filter_input(lum_picker.value, 0, 100);

    // (background has a fixed 50% luminosity)
    div.style.backgroundColor = "hsl(" + hue + ", " + sat  + "%, 50%)";
    txt.style.color = "hsl(" + hue + ", " + sat  + "%, " + lum + "%)";
    
    // Update the text to display current HSL values
    txt.innerText = "background-color: hsl(" + hue + ", " + sat  + "%, 50%);\n"
                  + "color: hsl(" + hue + ", " + sat  + "%, " + lum + "%);";
}

hue_picker.onchange = hue_picker.oninput = update_color;
sat_picker.onchange = sat_picker.oninput = update_color;
lum_picker.onchange = lum_picker.oninput = update_color;
```

```css
#div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
}

#txt {
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" id="hue-picker" value="0" min="0" max="360" step="1"/>
<input type="range" id="sat-picker" value="100" min="0" max="100" step="1"/>
<input type="range" id="lum-picker" value="75" min="0" max="100" step="1"/>
<div id="div">
    <span id="txt">Text With Background</span>
</div>
```

Hopefully this is still relevant / useful to you! Cheers!